Debt collections
can I please get some help. So recently I was going through my junk emails folder and I came across a email from a debt collector saying they are trying to collect money for a apartment and listed the name I’ve never lived in a apartment so I look up the name and I’m not even familiar with the complex. This was about a week ago , but today I wake up to a notification from my credit report stating to me that a report has been added and it’s about that debt for those apartments. How do I go about this? What do I do please somebody help me or give me advice how do I dispute this ? If I can I’m a college student and just now trying to build my credit and now I have this and I’ve never even lived there

The credit report you're looking at should have a link or phone number for disputing incorrect information.  Just make sure when you do dispute, you pick the correct reason (likely "someone else's record is wrongly listed on my report").  You don't want to dispute the date, or amount, or say it's already been paid -- any of those would convince them that they found the right person.

Have you checked your real credit report by going directly to the official site, not just by clicking links in email/text notifications?

You want to dispute this debt as it is not yours. Are you 100% sure the email is regarding the same debt? If so (do not click links in the email), call the debt collector directly, and ask for them to provide proof of debt. Say something like "I received an email regarding a debt to "Apartment" please send me a written notice to my current address at: "Home". DO NOT give them any other personal info. If the debt is real (read: they are not scamming) then they should already have all your personal info.
Then, you want to go to wherever you viewed your credit report and dispute the debt with something like "this debt does not belong to me". As Ben Voigt said in his comment, do not dispute the dates, amounts, or any other details of the debt as that may give legitimacy to their claims. It would not hurt to go to annualcreditreport.com and get your full credit report to make sure you have all the details.
As long as you are proactive with the debt collector and credit reporter this should be figured out relatively quickly. It is up to the debt collector to prove that you owe that debt but if you don't work with them then it will continue to travel through the chain.
